# Noob Question about a discrete surface

Tags: calculus, discrete-mathematics, 3d

I am looking for a nudge in the right direction as to how to solve this problem.

I have data which defines a solid cylinder. The data is composed of a 3d internal radius and a thickness at each point in reference to a center axis (thickness is a separate data set from radius).

I am trying to write logic functions which describe inconsistencies in the data, such as holes (which would show up as sudden peaks through the total expected thickness), reductions in thickness (hills), whether the change begins internally or externally, or even increases in thickness (and whether it is internally or externally based on the expected surface).

I started out using differentials to compare slopes and set thresholds of what would be considered what I define.

Any good references or pushes in the right direction would be great! I am writing this all in C++ (sort of).

Here is an example of the type of data and my logic. I have normalized the radius to expected so that any change from 0 is addition or reduction from the expected surface. Likewise for the thickness. For this example I am taking 12 measurements of a cross section of the cylinder. The cylinder has an expected thickness of 0.5.

internal Raduis [0,0,0,0.1,0.3,0.5,0.5,0.3,0.1,0,0,0]

Thickness [0,0,0,-0.1,-0.3,-0.5,-0.5,-0.3,-0.1,0,0,0]

So for this example, there is an internal hole.

internal Raduis [0,0,0,0,0,0.5,0.5,0,0,0,0,0]

Thickness [0,0,0,-0.1,-0.3,-0.5,-0.5,-0.3,-0.1,0,0,0]

For this example, there is an external hole.

The data sets I am using are typically 100 x ~30000 x (-1 to +1)

Thanks to all that consider helping me.